# Project Specific Tasks - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, task

I am trying to create a task via the task view in eclipse for a specific project. However when changing projects the tasks stay the same.

Is there any way to differentiate between the projects.

This is my current list to a work project, I do not want this PHP work project to be shown in my learning c* project(s) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) can do this (and a *lot* more). It's included in most of the recent Eclipse downloadable packages.